# python не могу подключиться к pyodbc

Tags: python

Мои драйвера:

```
import pyodbc

for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
    print(driver)
```

> SQL Server
>
> Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
>
> Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
>
> Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
>
> Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)
>
> Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
>
> Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
>
> Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
>
> Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
>
> Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
>
> Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
>
> Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
>
> Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
>
> Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
>
> Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
>
> Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
>
> Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)
>
> Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver
>
> Microsoft FoxPro VFP Driver (*.dbf)
>
> Microsoft dBase VFP Driver (*.dbf)
>
> Microsoft Visual FoxPro-Treiber
>
> Driver para o Microsoft Visual FoxPro
>
> Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
>
> Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
>
> Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)
>
> Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
>
> ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
>
> SQL Native Client
>
> SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Пишу:

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = 'test'
username = 'sa'
password = ''
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn =     pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+databas    e+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName     FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON     pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
row = cursor.fetchone()
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\Python\file.py", line 43, in <module>
cnxn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Поставщик именованных каналов: Не удалось открыть соединение с SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Время ожидания входа в систему истекло. (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Недопустимый атрибут строки подключения (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]При установлении соединения с сервером SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и на сервере SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. Дополнительные сведения см. в электронной документации по SQL Server. (53)')
```

Где мне брать данные для подключения? Все пишут данные из MC SQL и все работает, а у меня не получается

Вообще имя сервера вот это, но с ним тоже не хочет работать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Исправление № 1**

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = (
    r"Driver={SQL Server};"
    r"Server=ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS;"
    r"Database=test;"
    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    )
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Выдает следующее:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\Python\file.py", line 44, in 
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server не существует, или доступ запрещен. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')
[Finished in 31.7s with exit code 1]

Comment: Вместо `<server>.database.windows.net` нужно указывать имя или ip адрес вашего экземпляра SQL Server. Имя скорее всего будет `ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ-ПК` или `ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ-ПК\SQLEXPRESS`. Если подключаетесь локально, то `localhost` или `localhost\sqlexpress` должно сработать. Если подключаетесь к этому компьютеру по сети, то еще в брандмауэере должен быть открыт 1433 порт для подключения извне, и еще в SQL Server Configuration Server должен быть включено подключение по TCP: [ссылка](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/isv_team/2011/04/16/sql-server-108-2/)

Comment: @insolor когда я пишу имя сервера ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ-ПК\SQLEXPRESS, то \S выделяется оранжевым. Полагаю, что из-за этого могут быть какие-то ошибки. Как в питоне убрать это выделение? (я исправил вопрос, см. исправление № 1)

Comment: Тогда так: `r'ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ-ПК\SQLEXPRESS'` или `'ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS'`.

Comment: @insolor я ввел, что вы сказали и добавил ошибку в вопрос в конце

Comment: Тогда выполните запрос `select @@servername`, и попробуйте это имя сервера (если отличается от того что до этого вводили).

Answer (score 0):

Пересмотре много сайтов была также проблема ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ из pyodbc.connect()  скрипт на centOC7 сервер MSSQL 2017 стоял в сети на windows 10 .переставлял pyodbc и драйвер к нему на sql порт прописывал.Искал причину как и многие другие вроде как в driver = {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server } как и многим все это не помогало просто описание ошибки явно не указывает на причину! Указывает на то что не может подключится к драйверу, а на самом деле ОП! защитник windows на 10 Винде не давал подключение, отрубил его наблюдение в реальном времени и все тип топ.успехов всем в нашем нелёгком но ИНТЕРЕСНОМ труде.